# Looking for a lightweight MP3 player for OS X

Tags: mp3

I'm looking for something, preferably free, to play MP3s in OS X in a way they don't automatically get dumped into iTunes. Any suggestions?

Songbird is not lightweight.

VLC I use for videos.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you prefer a dedicated app rather than use **Quick Look**, check **[Vox](https://vox.rocks/mac-music-player)**, *the lightweight music app for Mac OS X*.
It's free but you can donate.

Comment: I'd say that Vox is not lightweight.  It requires you to make playlists instead of just playing all the highlighted files.  Most of the time I just want to play a few songs (organized in folders) without searching through the thousands in my playlist.

Comment: Not lightweight anymore... But you can probably run an older version

Comment: It also requires me to log in - I sort of hate that, I just want to play some of my local mp3s, this is annoying

Answer (score 6):

Quicktime player. Quicktime player.

Comment: Just did a quick test playing a 44mb mp3 with Vox and QuickTime, both the lastest versions. Quickly scrubbing the mp3 back and forth used the most processor, just playing it was non-max usage. **Vox**: cpu 2.3%, cpu max 5.0%, memory 11.3mb. **QuickTime**: cpu 2.8%, cpu max 7.1%, memory 35.4mb. **Conclusion**: neither is a pig, but Vox is definitely lighter, especially in memory use.

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted my answer. Quicktime is free (as in beer) and light. That's what i use anyway when I don't want to add mp3's to my iTunes library.

Comment: +1: I think QuickTime Player is a reasonable suggestion here.

Comment: I don't know, @Rafael, your answer is certainly completely valid, even if it's not what the OP ended up using.

Comment: Quicktime player won't play more than one song back-to-back.

Comment: Hello from the future. If it can't handle a playlist, it's not much of a music player. This disqualifies Quicktime in my eyes.

(Full disclosure: While I think lack of playlist functionality is very solid grounds for disqualification, I'm admittedly biased against Quicktime from the outset.)

Comment: It plays music, it's a music player. Lightweight is going to mean fewer features, and OP didn't specify needing playlists. I think it's a perfectly reasonable recommendation—particularly as QuickTime is in fact *my* primary music player!

Answer (score 6):

**This probably isn't what you're looking for**, but it so happens that the very lightest of lightweight music players is preinstalled on every Mac. No, it's not QuickTime, and it's not QuickLook—you already knew about those, and they're not as lightweight. We can do better.

Open a Terminal and type:

> afplay path/to/song.mp3

Your music will begin playing. No, there's no UI—you said you wanted something lightweight, didn't you?

To stop the song, press <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

To pause, press <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, then resume with the terminal command `fg`.

If you want playlists, you can do that too:

> afplay song1.mp3 && afplay song2.mp3 && afplay song3.mp3

Enjoy listening to music with the satisfaction that none of your precious processing power is being wasted on modern extravagances.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks mate

Comment: Do you know how to set afplay to a default sounder player in mac?

Comment: @HuibinZhang I don't think you can set command line apps as default file handlers. What you could do is create an Applescript app, or a shell script wrapped in a `.app` wrapper. You might consider asking a new question (it could link to this answer) with details on exactly what effect you're trying to achieve—for instance, do you want a terminal window, or should music play without any visible indication whatsoever? My answer was mostly intended as a joke, tbqh.

Comment: thanks I also tried to set that as default file handlers but wasn't able, as it grey out and system won't allow me to set that to a default file handers. I don't want ui to be present to be honest, that is why I want to have this afplay as default player.

Comment: Hi @Wowfunhappy I have submit a new questions here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388197/how-to-set-afplay-as-default-media-player-for-wma-files-in-mac-os. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a vim plugin called eblook.vim, it could search turn vim into a dictionary, as it use the eblook api to query diction file in ebz format, but the problem is when there is some word contains pronunciation, it will have to link to a media player to handle the play, I would prefer to have it been handled by afplay instead of other UI based sound player, for example itunes or vlc etc. The current implementation of the eblook.vim scripts will use the default player for wma format file to play it, but I want to have afplay instead, as it doesn't have UI is much quicker than itune

Comment: I got error message when use afplay to open a wav file,  Error: AudioFileOpen failed ('dta?') do you know what does this mean? I open the wav file from terminal it works fine, but I changed the vim scripts to call this command, it gives me this error.

Comment: sorry to disturb you. I got error message when use afplay to open a wav file,  Error: AudioFileOpen failed ('dta?') and I rename the wav file to mp3, then it can be played. But in the vim plugin I don't know how to do the same rename file, as the file was extracted by scripts and default to wav.

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for the perfect lightweight OSX player for a long time and still stick with [Cog](https://cogx.org/)

Change the update feed to Nightly in the preferences and you'll get 0.08 that runs in High Sierra and lower.

UPDATE: An active fork is now available at https://kode54.net/cog (thanks OleGG for the mentioning it)

Comment: I used Cog for a lot of years, until the stable version stopped working and I was sad. I just came across this now, and the latest "nightly" from ~2013 does indeed still work!  Considering that this player is effectively defunct, I'm not sure it's necessarily a good answer, but I really appreciated this and I'm using it again, so I'm upvoting.

Comment: Thanks @adfaklsdjf, yes, I had the same kind of Eureka moment when I discovered the nightly build :-)

Comment: It took me some time to find a "nightly" from cogx.org ... and eventually found in the forums that the project has been forked and that (as of this comment!), a working Cog for Mojave (10.14.6) can be found at [https://mamburu.net/cog/](https://mamburu.net/cog/).

Comment: Cog indeed has a supported fork in active development https://kode54.net/cog/

Answer (score 2):

I usually default to using VLC but it has one annoying (to me) limitation: playlists do not persist when you close the app. (At least, I can't find a way of overcoming this in the preferences.) I have used Cog, but after recent updates of OS X (I'm now on Mojave) it seems very flakey. So....

#### [Pine Player](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pine-player/id1112075769?mt=12)

After a bit of a search, I've now found **[Pine Player](http://www.pineplayer.com/)** ("Price: Free") which is also available in [the App store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pine-player/id1112075769?mt=12). It has some other nice features, too, but is a fairly simple player and so lacks some features that users might like to have (e.g., I don't think it varies speed of playback). But it is a nicely implemented audio player with "persistent" playlists, and that's exactly what I'm looking for. Works well for me!

[image: screenshot_of_pine_player]

Comment: Reminds me of Winamp. There's no button to add a song to the playlist ‍♂️ At least I didn't find one. I added songs with the menu `File -> Open ...`

Answer (score 1):

On Finder, click the mp3, press <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

It will open a **Quick Look** window and that will preview your mp3.

Comment: @idober Quick Look does play the mp3 and offers basic controls: play/pause and a scrubber for changing position in the track. However it only works if you don't leave the Finder or click on anything else in Finder. Still, I wanted to clarify that for future people reading this question.

Comment: If you use column view, you can also use the preview column to play it, and it won't stop playing if you switch applications or windows.

Comment: Works perfectly for playing just one song.  But if you want anymore (like say, an album) you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleSong](http://earthpeople.se/labs/2010/09/sing-a-simple-song/) seems to be exactly what you are searching for - this is as simple as it gets, basically just a searchbar. You can now also drag tracks from the finder to the dock icon, to open the tracks as a playlist.

Comment: New versions of the OS have replaced SimpleSong with Quick Look.  And in the time, it has gotten less compatible (and therefore buggy).  Too bad; it looked pretty nice.