# how to set afplay as default media player for wma files in mac OS

Tags: mac, script, vi, macvim, mediaplayer

Hi I am using a vim plugin named [eblook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEEDm.png) which turns vim console into a dictionary. The problem is that the implementation of the plugin is using a default player for WMA file to play the sound file (for example pronunciation of a certain word in the dictionary).

I would like to use afplay as the default media player in Mac so that when I use the plugin, all sound can be played without need to use iTunes or any other UI based media player (due to overhead of iTunes or any other UI based media player)

[image: try set to use afplay as default media player for wma files]

[image: The eblook.vim plugin]

Answer (score 1):

You can only associate file types to GUI apps. You should be able to make an Automator app that is a wrapper for the afplay command, and that will have minimal "overhead".